# Passing function to another component getting error this is not defined react js

Tags: reactjs

I am developing an app with sliding menu in react but I am getting the following error.

this is not defined

My code

Myfile

```
const toggleMenu = () => {
    alert("clicked");
    state = !state
    if (state === false) {
        const visibllity = "close";
        alert("open")
    } else {
        const viisibility = "open"
        alert("close")
    }

}
return (
    <RiderHeader toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu()} />
)
```

RiderHeader.js

```
 return (
    <div className="user-header">
        <IconButton onClick={() => toggleMenu()}>
           <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </div>
 )
```

Comment: `<RiderHeader toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu} />` - I think you have to pass function to the RiderHeader

Comment: ComponentA  is function component or class component?

Comment: First of all, what is the location of components A and B? are they both on the same file or different files? What error are you getting?

Comment: @mw509 they are in different files

Comment: I have updated my question

Comment: How are you including/importing/referencing the file from one to the other?

Answer (score 0):

thisYou shouldn't call the function when you are declaring (or passing it as a prop).

```
<Component prop={this.func} /> or <Component prop={() => this.func()} />
```

In you file where toggleMenu is defined,

```
return (
    <RiderHeader toggleMenu={this.toggleMenu} />
)
```

In RiderHeader.js,
If it's a class component then,

```
return (
    <div className="user-header">
        <IconButton onClick={() => this.props.toggleMenu()}>
        {/* or
           <IconButton onClick={this.props.toggleMenu}>
        */}
           <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </div>
 )
```

If it's a functional component,

```
return (
    <div className="user-header">
        <IconButton onClick={() => props.toggleMenu()}>
        {/* or
           <IconButton onClick={props.toggleMenu}>
        */}
           <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>
    </div>
 )
```